# Cordova App Access SD Card

Tags: android, ajax, xml, cordova, local-storage

I'm preparing a cordova app for ios and android. On android, my app downloading a zip file and extract it into sdcard. This zip file contains some xml files and some jpegs. But unfortunately i cant access to xml files via `$.ajax`.

i tried following paths;

`cdvfile://sdcard/webservice/Resim/Kategori.xml`

`cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Resim/Kategori.xml'`

And my ajax looks like;

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'cdvfile://sdcard/webservice/Resim/Kategori.xml',
   dataType: 'xml',
   async:false,
   cache:false,
   success: parseMenu
});
```

What is wrong with my ajax request? I tried send `xml` file into `www` directory before i build app and it works with this path `'../webservice/Resim/Kategori.xml'`

How can i access my downloaded xml via `$.ajax` or should i download it into `android_asset/www/webservice` path, if yes how can i download it to there?

PS: My download and extract function executes good, if needed;

```
function appReady(){
                alert('tamam');
            }
            var filePath = "/sdcard/";

            //İndirelecek dosyanın URL yolu
            var zipURL = "http://www.somedomain.com/webservice/webservice.zip";

            //İndirilen dosyanın alacağı isim.
            var fileName = "webservice.zip";

            function downloadZip() {
                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

                fileTransfer.download(
                    encodeURI(zipURL),
                    filePath + fileName,
                    function(entry) {

                        zip.unzip(filePath+ fileName, filePath, appReady, null);
                        alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        alert(error);
                        alert("download error source " + error.source);
                        alert("download error target " + error.target);
                    },
                    false,
                    {

                    }
                );

            }
            function init(){

                // eğer indirilmediyse..
                if(localStorage.getItem('downloaded') != "yes") {
                    alert('inmemiş inecek..');
                    // uygualama ana klasörünü dosya yolu olarak belirledim siz değişebilirsiniz.
                    alert(filePath);
                    // zip dosyasını indir
                    downloadZip();

                } else {
                    alert('İnmiş gözüküyor');
                    // uygulamanızı çalıştıran fonksiyon olduğunu varsaydım.
                    appReady();
                }      

            }
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
```

Comment: you have to use file system in order to use your directories inside storage . Since Cordova is a webview, it doesnot have full access. so you need to use via libraries. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066175/cordova-store-fileentry-name-to-string/30067414#30067414

Comment: @MohammedImranN does it need any extra library or pure javascript?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: @MohammedImranN i got that plugin in my app. Can you please point me out how can i resolve sdcard storage path?

Comment: Have you tried this path: `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'webservice/Resim/Kategori.xml'`? You are extracting it into the folder `webservice` and you tried to open the `Resim` folder which is inside it. And don't use quotes around `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` just around the end of the path.

Comment: @Timo i tried that path it doesn't access to xml. In my ajax request url there is no quotes near `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory`